# reading .opus audio files in python

Tags: python, librosa, opus

I'm trying to use librosa to read an .opus file but it runs forever and doesn't load anything (I've waited for around 30 minutes for a 51MB file and still nothing).

Here is the code I am using

```
path_to_opus = '/my/path/to/file.opus'
y, sr = librosa.load(path_to_opus, sr=16000)
```

Is there a good way of reading .opus audio files in python fast?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at the librosa documentation you can specify a *res_type* field that sounds to be useful for you.
This is a quote [from the doc](http://man.hubwiz.com/docset/LibROSA.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/generated/librosa.core.load.html):

*res_type : str*

> By default, this uses resampy’s high-quality mode (‘kaiser_best’).
>
> To use a faster method, set res_type=’kaiser_fast’.
>
> To use scipy.signal.resample, set res_type=’scipy’.

You could try something like:

```
X, sr = librosa.load('myfile.opus', res_type='kaiser_fast', ...)
```